# Using WGET to Get Links on the Page

Tags: href, wget

I'm using:

```
wget --spider --force-html -r -l5 http://example.com 2>&1 | grep '^--' | awk '{print $3}' > urls.txt
```

It works great; however, it doesn't seem to copy the 'href=' links on each page.

```
wget -q http://example.com -O - | \
tr "\t\r\n'" '   "' | \
grep -i -o '<a[^>]\+href[ ]*=[ \t]*"\(ht\|f\)tps\?:[^"]\+"' | \
sed -e 's/^.*"\([^"]\+\)".*$/\1/g'>urls.txt
```

This second one does grab the href links I'm looking for, but it doesn't spider.

I'm trying to make the first one accept href links on each page or the second one perform spider. I'm aware there are better tools to do this, but I have to use WGET in this example.

Answer (score -1):

`wget` does not offer such an option. Please read its man page.

You could use `lynx` for this:

```
lynx -dump -listonly http://aligajani.com | grep -v facebook.com > file.txt
```

From its man page:

```
   -listonly
          for -dump, show only the list of links.
```

*Copy of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116987/how-do-i-use-wget-to-download-all-links-from-my-site-and-save-to-a-text-file)*

Comment: usually I would however the page is prompting me to accept cookies. When I do accept all cookies in lynx settings it still prompts me again for cookies. I can give you the link if you want.